# @Transactional rollback not working in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a `@Component` layer that calls two functions.
I forced my second function to return an Exception but it the first transaction didn't rollback.
This Service layer is annotated with `@Transactional`

```
@Transactional
class {

void updateMessageResult() {
    Message updatedMessage = messageService.updateResult(message, messageQueueDto);
    messagePublisher.publishEvent(updatedMessage);
 }
}
```

In `publishEvent` it forced to throw the RuntimeException

```
public void publishEvent()  {
throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Update: I tried the suggestions but it still won't rollback

Comment: There is no indication on where/how you setup transaction management. None of the code you are showing will on it's own result in a rollback of anything.

Comment: @ChristianFrommeyer but `@EnableTransactionManagement` is on by default. :(

Comment: @mengmeng but by default it would AFAIK just work for the immediate DB operation not for a higher level method unless you annotate that method with `@Transactional`. And there is no such annotation in your question.

Comment: @ChristianFrommeyer I thought its already understood in my title that the class has a `@Transactional` annotation. I'll edit

Comment: @mengmeng I don't have recent experience working with transaction capable queues. Are you sure transaction management is also automatic for your queue? Assuming that `messageService` is not talking to a DB but a queue.

Comment: @ChristianFrommeyer hi. `messageService` is a service that updates entities. Not a queue. huhu. But this class I'm working on is the one that listens to a queue.

Comment: how do you call updateMessageResult ? Is it from the same class ? Is messageService using spring transaction management ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting the wrong code. I just typed the code instead of copy pasting it.

The answer is I forgot to add the accessor (or public) for the method.

If you won’t specify the accessor of method in Java, the default accessor would be default.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable transaction management in your project ?

For example, annotating your configuration class with **@EnableTransactionManagement**

One more thing: transaction roll-back with @Transactional only works with RuntimeException(or its subclass) by default. Make sure that the exception you throw is RuntimeException

Comment: Hi. I tried enabling it. and throw RunTimeException instead of IllegalAccessException. But it still won't rollback :(

Answer (score 0):

Use **@Transactional** annotation at the method level where you want the transaction. It should work.